# How to deal with duplicate keys

Tags: mysql, sql

**tblA**

id

**tblB**

id, id2

I want to check if tbl A ID exists in tbl B ID BUT NOT look at id2, 
The id2 column in tblB will have keys that are present in tblA.

```
SELECT id
FROM tblA as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM tblB AS b
WHERE a.id = b.id
)
```

Logically, this should work but for some reason, it also gives me the values that are present in the id2 column in tblB which don't exist in tblA id

Sample Data

**tblA**

```
ID 
1
2 
3
4
```

**tblB**

```
tblb_ID   | ID2 
3         | 34
4         | 38 
12        | 93
43        | 54
54        | 4
```

**Expected Result**

1,2 because 1 and 2 doesn't exist in tblB.

**What i get,**

Only 1, because 4 exists in ID2, why is this?

Comment: Please, if you could add some sample data and the expected result, that will be useful to clarify your question.

Comment: Do you sure, you get only `id: 1` from your query, check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aY6kwu1VVnj6m6u6FmanzX/0. It gives me ids `1` and `2`. Maybe your sample set is not consistent with your explanation?

Comment: I would agree with D. Smania comment -- your code should work even though it's similar to the solution I provided in function.  Something else must explain your results, because your EXISTS query should work.

Comment: @Will Driver with id number `22` is in your query result because there is not any id number `22` on the column `raceEntryDriverId` of the table `MoSpo_RaceEntry`. The id number `22` appears only in the column `raceEntryCarId` of that table, that have relations with cars, not with drivers.

Comment: @Will I'm going crazy, lol, if you check: the ID number `22 ` isn't on the column `raceEntryDriverId` and that is why it appears on your query. Don't you wanted just this: _I only want all the drivers who are not in the `raceEntryDriverId`_

Comment: Oh god, i think I have been trying to fix a problem that doesn't exist for 5+ hours. I'm sorry I wasted everyone's time

Comment: Yeah came to the same conclusion.  Your query worked all along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be very simple, if I understand your question.  You only want rows from tblA where tblA.id does not match a tblB.id.  tblB.id2 doesn't matter.

```
 SELECT * FROM tblA WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT tblb_ID FROM tblB)
```

As commented, your original query should work.  Given your updated info, this looks like the correct query:

```
SELECT id
FROM tblA as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM tblB AS b
    WHERE a.id = b.tblb_ID
)
```

Comment: Modified to match your column names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM tblA WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tblB) AND id NOT IN (SELECT id2 FROM tblB)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM tblA AS a
LEFT JOIN tblB as b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

That *should* give you all of the values from A that do not exist in B, only comparing against B.id

Answer (score 0):

The description of the columns in your `tblB` is inconsistent with the sample data, which shows the first column as `tblb_ID`.  If that's the correct name, then

```
SELECT id
FROM tblA as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM tblB AS b
WHERE a.id = b.id
)
```

is invalid and should be flagged as a syntax error, because there's no
`b.id`.  If that's not the case, you have a bug to report.

That said, I would modify the recommended fix to be

```
SELECT id
FROM tblA as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM tblB AS b
    WHERE a.id = b.tblb_ID
)
```

because that simplifies the work for the query processor and better conveys
your intention.

The meaning of `SELECT` and thus `SELECT *` is often misunderstood.
`SELECT` is the SQL implementation of PROJECT in relational algebra:
it specifies which *columns* (not rows) to return.  `SELECT *` returns
all columns; if SQL weren't a relic from the era of 4th generation
languages, we could dispense with `SELECT *` because *project all* is
the same as *no projection*.

In an existence test, there's no projection, i.e.*no columns are
selected*.  All the critical information is in `FROM` and `WHERE`.  A
row -- the whole row -- either meets the `WHERE` test or it does not.
The value of the row isn't returned anywhere.  It's not available to
the outer query, for instance.  The "select" meaningless; it's is
there only because the syntax requires it.

By saying `SELECT 1`, we're emphasizing that it's a boolean test and
that nothing is being "selected" *per se*.